# Microsoft Outlook adding Hyperlink to Email C#

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

When sending an e-mail using Microsoft Outlook I want to be able to send a hyperlink of file locations and websites in the body of the e-mail the body in my code is oMsg.Body. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Send Routing and Drawing to Dan
        // Create the Outlook application by using inline initialization. 
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        //Create the new message by using the simplest approach. 
        Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        //Add a recipient
        Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oMsg.Recipients.Add("email-address here");
        oRecip.Resolve();
        //Set the basic properties. 
        oMsg.Subject = textBox1.Text + " Job Release";
        oMsg.Body = textBox1.Text + " is ready for release attached is the Print and Routing";
        //Send the message. 6
        oMsg.Send();
        //Explicitly release objects. 
        oRecip = null;
        oMsg = null;
        oApp = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Print and Routing Sent");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using HTML for the Body instead of plain text will allow you to include markup for hyperlinks:

```
oMsg.HTMLBody = "<html><body>";
oMsg.HTMLBody += textBox1.Text + " is ready for release attached is the Print and Routing";
oMsg.HTMLBody += "<p><a href='http://website.com'>Web Site</a></p></body></html>";
```

EDIT: Changed `Body` property to `HTMLBody` property.

Comment: "<html><body>"; "<p><a href='http://website.com'>Web Site</a></p></body></html>"; 
show up in the email

Answer (score 7):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868941.aspx), looks like you can set the `BodyFormat` to `olFormatHTML` and use the `HTMLBody` property:

```
oMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML; // <-- Probably dont need this
oMsg.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here.</BODY></HTML>";
```

From the [`HTMLBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171418%28v=office.11%29.aspx) page, it looks like it sets the `BodyFormat` for you if you use the `HTMLBody` property, so you should be able to skip setting it.